# Auto create article in a django application

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django app that shows blog posts. Here is my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self):
        super(Article, self).save()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to create a bot that reads a file and automatically creates posts every 3h. How would I go about to create something like that. And where can i write this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). You must define a function with the @task decorator (normally I use a tasks.py file inside my app directory).

When configuring celery, you can tell it to launch a periodic task. For this, you need celerybeat enabled also.

[Here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) you have info about how to configure periodic tasks with celery.

And [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) you have info about configuring celery with Django.